# python - understanding of for loop

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following line in a python code:

```
for tradeName, trade in data.iterrows():
    ...
```

"data" being a pandas dataframe in the following form:

```
timestamp           open    high    low     close   volume          
2000-01-03 00:00:00 1481.50 1481.50 1480.50 1480.50 4
2000-01-03 00:30:00 1480.25 1480.50 1479.75 1480.50 4
2000-01-03 01:00:00 1480.50 1481.50 1480.50 1481.25 7
```

I dont understand how for loop works in such case, especially with the expression `for tradeName, trade...`
what are those names referring to? esp that they dont appear in the dataframe header and are not specified anywhere else?

Comment: Did you try adding `print(tradeName, trade)` at the top of your loop to see what those variables were?

Comment: Or, did you take a look at [the iterrows API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html): "Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs."

Comment: Be careful with `iterrows`, it is incredibly slow if you have a large DataFrame.  `itertuples` is **MUCH** faster because it does not need to construct a Series object for each row of data.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things going on here, first is unpacking and second is looping.

You can unpack elements in a tuple and assign them simultaneously as follows:

```
a,b,c = tuple([1,2,3])
print(b)
```

Further, if you have an iterable of tuples, you can unpack each one sequentially.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b','c']

for x,y in zip(a,b):
    print(x)
    print(y)

# to see what zip(a,b) is
print([i for i in zip(a,b)])
```

So in the loop, each tuple in the iterable is unpacked into those variables, and available with each iteration of the loop!

Does that explain it?

Answer (score 2):

the tradeName and trade are just self defined  "loop" variables to get the respective value that data.iterrows() will return. TradName being the index and trade being the series for the index.

These below should return the same result:

```
    for tradeName, trade in data.iterrows():
    for x, y             in data.iterrows():
    for apple, orange    in data.iterrows():
```

Comment: I'm not sure that "dummy variable" is the right term.  Maybe "looping variable".

Comment: Rather than ask the OP for the output of `iterrows()`, it may be more instructive to describe what tuple unpacking is.  Then the OP will get a more general answer.

Comment: here is what is returned adding print (tradename, trade) at the top of the loop
(Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'), open          1481.50
high          1481.50
low           1480.50
close         1480.50
volume           4.00
tradeClose    1459.25
trend           -1.00
netgain       2512.50
Name: 2000-01-03 00:00:00, dtype: float64)
so i assume i can figure out now what they are.

Comment: @jimbasquiat Would you agree that the output looks like the DataFrame Index value, and then the remainder of the data on that row?  From that we can assume that `tradeName` contains the Index value for the row, and `trade` contains the row's data (it happens to be in a Series object).